# Can I specify percentages in keyframes?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, keyframe

For example, I'd like to specify 100%

```
@keyframes example {
    0%   {height: 0px;}
    100% {height: 100%;}
}

container {
    height: auto; //variable height
    animation-name: example;
}
```

since the height of the text box that I want to animate is variable.

Comment: Please provide explanations for downvotes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in setting an animation the way you ask:

```css
@keyframes example {
    0%   {height: 0px;}
    100% {height: 100%;}
}

.container {
    height: auto; 
    animation: example 2s infinite;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    width: 100px;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very confused as to what you are asking but this is my foolish assumption.  I assume you are asking if you can use % units in `@keyframes`.

Yes. you can use percents in CSS Keyframes.